# Not able to execute sdk manager commands from command line : Android

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I am not able to execute the sdkmanager from command line. if I execute `./sdkmanager --list`, I got following exception

Error: Could not find or load main class java.se.ee

Any help on this?

Comment: Which JDK version have you installed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077881/5952645 Check this for the fix.

Comment: finally got fixed by this link : - https://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/install-android-sdk-manager-linux-ubuntu-16-04/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved my issue by removing `-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee` in the `sdkmanager`

It was originally

```
# Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and SDKMANAGER_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=$APP_HOME" -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
```

and I removed -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee.

Now I can run sdkmanager commands